# Run as administrator does not work on windows server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server

When I need administrator privileges the only way I can do that is as Run as different user and enter administrator credentials. My user is in administrators group and run as administrator does not give any effect. Is it normal in windows server?

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Do note that even if your user is in the `administrators group`, if the program has security settings applied, and the `administrators group` does not have rights, while the administrator user (notice the missing s) has rights, it will cause problems like this.

Run as Administrator will run any program as your current user (the rights you have) but allows any administrative task to be passed (UAC).

Comment: I can not install any program without manipulation I mentioned previously. Is it normal?

Comment: Does the installer not even run, or does the install run but fail at some point?

Comment: it runs and after that fails because of permissions

Comment: So my answer is correct then. You need to set security rights to the folder where you wish to install your program to, and maybe also other places depending on what the installer wants to do. But usually program files is enough. I've seen Trusted Installer having all rights making any installation fail. Giving my own user rights fixed the issue.

Comment: the same issue I have with Control Panel, Server Manager and so on